# gradle, jetty and servlet - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: gradle, jetty

I am trying to run this simple example
https://github.com/gradle/oreilly-gradle-book-examples/tree/master/web-hello-world

after cloning the repo,

```
cd oreilly-gradle-book-examples/web-hello-world
gradle JettyRun
```

Seems to be working fine

```
compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Building 75% > :jettyRun > Running at http://localhost:8080/web-hello-world
```

When I access that URL though, I simply get

```
Directory: /web-hello-world/
web.xml     555 bytes   Jul 30, 2017 4:55:48 PM
```

so the servlet code isnt being called.

Using Gradle 3.4.1
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like web.xml needs to be under a folder named WEB-INF. Didnt change anything though.

Comment: Did you try to access `/web-hello-world/hello`? The Jetty **server** is running at `http://localhost:8080/web-hello-world`, but the **servlet** is mapped to `/hello`, as you can see in the `web.xml` file.

Comment: yep eventually I figured that out.... even though now I do have the WEB-INF folder so not sure that alone would do.

Will try reverting back and let you know... thanks :)

Comment: I also having the same problem. Do you found your solution? This is my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835410/use-gradle-jettyrun-to-start-a-stripes-web-application